# WPF Exception when try animating binding foreground

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this control…:

```
<iconPack:PackIconAlvo
    Width="{StaticResource iconSize}"
    Height="{StaticResource iconSize}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Foreground="{Binding IsMonitoringButtonActive, Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedToColorConverter}}"
    Kind="Monitoring"
    Style="{StaticResource AlarmAnimation}" />
```

…with this converter…:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return (bool)value ? new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 161)) : new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(131, 131, 131));
}
```

…and this animation style:

```
<Style x:Key="AlarmAnimation">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAlarmForMonitoringButton}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            From="Gray"
                            To="Red"
                            Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When I start animation (IsAlarmForMonitoringButton == true) and IsMonitoringButtonActive == false, then I have error:

> Cannot animate 'Foreground.(0)' on an immutable object instance.

I can't deal with this error. It is important in this application that the foreground is variable, it is also important that it is animated when IsAlarmForMonitoringButton==true.

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Foreground` property using a `Style` instead of using a binding expression and a converter, e.g.:

```
<iconPack:PackIconAlvo
        Width="{StaticResource iconSize}"
        Height="{StaticResource iconSize}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Kind="Monitoring">
    <iconPack:PackIconAlvo.Style>
        <Style TargetType="iconPack:PackIconAlvo">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMonitoringButtonActive}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAlarmForMonitoringButton}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation
                                    AutoReverse="True"                                
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    From="Gray"
                                    To="Red"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </iconPack:PackIconAlvo.Style>
</iconPack:PackIconAlvo>
```

The other option is to apply the animation programmatically.